# regex matches dot but not at the end

Tags: regex

I should write a regex for a filename, it has allowed chars

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+,._&-]+$
```

but it can't finish with a dot.

can I put the two together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a negative look-ahead at the beginning:

```
^(?!.*\.$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+,._&-]+$
  ^^^^^^^
```

The `(?!.*\.$)` look-ahead will be "triggered" in the beginning of the input, and will fail the match once a literal dot is found at the end of the string.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP9kY6/1)

Also, you can use another version with a negative-lookbehind (if the regex engine supports it). Here is a bad example of the look-behind based solution as it will perform lots of unnecessary backtracking:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+,._&-]+(?<!\.)$
```

Here is a better one as it has a possessive quantifier that will eliminate unnecessary backtracking and will check for the period only at the end of the string:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+,._&-]++(?<!\.)$
                     ^^
```

An alternative to the possessive quantifier is an atomic group:

```
^(?>[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+,._&-]+)(?<!\.)$
 ^^^                     ^
```

Comment: What about this `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+,._&-]+[^.]$`

Comment: @Uchiha: Look-arounds do not consume text, just check if there is something before or after the current position in a string. Negated character classes (like `[^.]`) do consume text. If there is a requirement *match at least 2 characters*, then yes, it is possible to use the expression. Still, it is not that efficient as the version with the look-ahead anchored at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for that awesome explanation. I really personally fond of your answers and explanation +1